# joint controller in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i created a linear joint . basically, it is like a linear actuator only can move up and down like the pr2 torso. but i stuck at making it moves in gazebo. Is there any gazebo plugin for it ? or do i have to write a controller? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202567/joint-controller-in-gazebo/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A working example can be found with the  [rrbot tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control) on ros_control. Have you tried this ? Or is it not what you are looking for ? I think you have to write your own controller. I am not sure if there are generic position and effort controllers available as plugging.

---

Originally posted by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) with karma: 285 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-02-09**:
Good answer. I don't think you have to write your own controller though, one of the joint position controllers in ros_control should do the trick, as shown in the rrbot tutorial.